# VHDL variable check in clk cycle

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to compare two values in a clk cycle
eg:

```
if(riding_edge(clk)) then
  if (some signal = other) then
    other<=other+1;
  else other<=other;

  if(other=3)then
    flag=1;
  end if;

 end if;
```

The code compiles and runs fine but when I am seeing the simulation window, the flag gets set no matter what is the value of other. Am I doing something wrong or the value of other is fluctuating. 
The above is a pseudo code and everything is correct syntactically.
Please Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post real code, not pseudo.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal working example, I could only guess that you're inferring a latch by not specifying what happens to `flag` when `other` is not 3.  To prevent this, you would specify all cases of any decision tree.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;    

ENTITY  example IS
   PORT (some_signal      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         other            : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         clk              : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         flag             : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        );
END example;

ARCHITECTURE minimal OF example IS

BEGIN 

minexample:PROCESS(clk)
BEGIN
IF (clk'EVENT and clk='1') THEN
      IF some_signal = other THEN
         other <= other + '1';
      ELSE other <= other;
      END IF;

      IF(other = '1') THEN
         flag <= '1';
      ELSE flag <= '0'; -- always specify all cases
      END IF;

END IF;

END PROCESS minexample;

END minimal;
```

Comment: sounds abour right, but shouldn't signal assignments be `<=` instead of `:=` ?

Comment: You're right.. I'm not near a compiler now and I was just converting some old code.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing but it is still stating the condition to be true, even if I add else condition. The problem I think is it, when it is fluctuating between values it gets 3 as well and set the flag as high and makes the condition true. I get what the problem is, but how do I solve it.

Comment: @user3217602 you need to rethink what you're trying to do.  If `some_signal` is '3' then flag will be true, else flag will be be false (after other increments enough to equal some_signal).. I would suggest putting  much more detail into your problem description.. and much more effort into making a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I use the code of N8TRO and add an reset to set the signal to zero at the startup and change the signal other to integer (because you like to check on the value 3) and check on rising_edge (should be the better way).

Now the signal flag should raise to high after 4 clocks after the Reset is set to low. Is this the behavior you expect?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;    

ENTITY  example IS
   PORT (some_signal      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         other            : IN  integer range 0 to 3; --this should be an integer 2 bit widht
         clk              : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         reset            : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         flag             : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        );
END example;

ARCHITECTURE minimal OF example IS

BEGIN 

minexample:PROCESS(clk,reset)
BEGIN
IF (reset = '1') then   --i think a reset is a good idea
      flag <= '0';
      other <= 0;
ELSIF (rising_edge(clk)) THEN
      IF some_signal = other THEN
         other <= other + 1;
      ELSE 
         other <= other;
      END IF;

      IF(other = 3) THEN --other is now an integer, so you can check on 3
         flag <= '1';
      ELSE 
         flag <= '0'; -- always specify all cases
      END IF;

END IF;

END PROCESS minexample;

END minimal;
```